# Constant MissingServletRequestParameterException

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, mockito

For some reason, I continously get the error message:

> MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String[] parameter
>   'ids' is not present

I have an endpoint which can be called from `/products?ids=["item1", "item2"]`

My integration test class looks like so:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductController controller;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFetchProducts() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/products")
                .param("ids[]", "[\"item\"]"))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

1. Using **param**

   ```
   @Test
   public void shouldFetchProducts() throws Exception {
       mockMvc.perform(get("/products")
               .param("ids[]", "[\"item\"]"))
               .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
   }
   ```
2. Using **requestAttr**

   ```
   @Test
   public void shouldFetchProducts() throws Exception {
       mockMvc.perform(get("/products")
           .requestAttr("ids[]", "[\"item\"]"))
           .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The name is `ids` not `ids[]`, you are also passing it in a non standard way. Normally you just pass the same parameter multiple times, however you are passing a deserialized array (unless that isn't what your controller or mapping is actually accepting).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
@Test
public void shouldFetchProducts() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/products")
            .param("ids", "item1", "item2"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

Documentation for `param` can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#param-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mkhanoyan, however, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `MultiValueMap` for this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
params.add("ids", "item1");
params.add("ids", "item2");
```

Now when you write your test-case, use the following:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/products")
            .params(params))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
```